# Unicode encoding issue with Parsing JSON to CSV using csvwriter

Tags: python, json, csv, unicode

Code:

```
with open(read_json,'r',encoding='utf-8') as json_file:

    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    print(json_data)
    with open(write_csv,'w',encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:

        headers, items = parse_json(json_data,query_type)
        # i is to be iterated to get all maxResults = 50.
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow(headers)
        for row in items:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

CSV file:

[image]
[image]

Im having weird characters in my CSV files not exactly sure whats happening.

Comment: That is UTF-8 multibyte characters displayed as the wrong code page, likely cp1252 if on Windows. Are you viewing the CSV in Excel or Notepad?  Use `utf-8-sig` as the encoding and it should fix the issue.

Comment: @MarkTolonen im using excel

Comment: @MarkTolonen it worked thank you so much, can you explain what went wrong, im new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows applications often assume text files are encoded in an ANSI encoding, which varies by localized Windows version. Windows-1252 is the encoding used by U.S. Windows.

Excel also makes this assumption, but if it sees a UTF8 BOM signature, it will use UTF8 for the encoding. Use the file encoding `utf-8-sig` to write this signature. If used to open a file for reading, it recognizes and discards the signature so it doesn't affect your Python code.

So use `utf-8-sig` instead to give Excel the hint it needs.